# sampling files from a folder

Tags: java

I have a folder containing 100000 files, and need to get 1000 files from this folder through random sampling. Are there any sample functions that I can use to sample from folder? In addition, how to copy the sampled files to another folder?

Comment: you should read first about [Java IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) before posting question on copy files in Java. All the answers are there.

Comment: are these file names structured by any pattern? because just listing a folder of 100000 files can take a very long time.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy  Good point(s).  The latter could change entirely how this is done, and make it much faster if the names are in a pattern we can predict in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random selection could follow along the following lines

```
File files[] = new File("/path/to/files").listFiles();
Map<Integer, File> selection = new HashMap<Integer, File>(1000);
while (selection.size() < 1000) {
    int value = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * files.length);
    if (!selection.containsKey(value)) {
        selection.put(value, files[value]);
    }
}
for (File file : selection.values()) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Essentially, you need to grab a list of the available files and the randomly pick through the list until you have enough of a sample.  Check out [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

There are plenty of examples of file copying over the net (and SO).  If you're really stuck you could have a look the [IO Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) or [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) which I believe has a utility class capable of coping files

**UPDATED**

As suggested by Andrew, you could simply shuffle the file list and pull the first 1000 elements...

```
File files[] = new File("/path/to/files").listFiles();
List<File> selection = null;
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(files));
Collections.shuffle(fileList);
selection = fileList.subList(0, Math.min(1000, fileList.size()));

for (File file : selection) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply shuffle the `File[]` and take the first `N` elements?

Comment: Or perhaps modified, in that `Collections` does not [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) arrays.  (Put them in a `List` first.)

Comment: OMG you really need that much code to do that in java? thank goodness I work with c#

Comment: I like the .shuffle() idea. it is indigenous, but, i won't do it this way. It doesn't help in code maintainability. Down the road somebody seeing this probably doesn't understand this. If the implementation changes, there are a million files, and he would only need to pick 5, this is an overkill implementation.

Comment: @chinboon that's a for comment, but with the right comments it shouldn't be an issue. It's also a lot faster the the first example ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
File f= new File("E:/Eclipse-Leo/Test/src/test/Desktop1");
List<File> randomFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
List<Integer> randNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if(f != null && f.isDirectory()){
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int idx = 1;

    while(idx <101 && idx >= 1)
    {

        int randTemp = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
        if(!randNumber.contains(randTemp))
        {
                 randNumber.add(randTemp);
                 randomFiles.add(files[randTemp]);
                 idx++;
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: What happens if you get duplicate random numbers?? I know that the requirement isn't mentioned but hay ;)

Answer (score 0):

File[] files = dir.listFiles();

Then just use files.length and a random number generator to index into the array.